# How to send request to Graph Api and fetch events data?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i am beginner to graph api/php . i want to get events data against page_id etc.when i paste url into browser it returns json data but when i use curl or  file_get_contents(); method it returns "Null". What is the proper way to sending request and getting response. this is my basic code and other than this i am NOT using any kind of include files etc.

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/getwellgabby/events/attending/?fields=id,name,description,timezone,start_time,cover&access_token=206516302813755|lRnrKAiu3Z......&since=1356998400&until=1483228800";

file_get_contents($json_link);

$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

 var_dump($json);
```

**RESULT**: boolean (false)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending

As you can see in the docs, the correct way to get attendees for an event is to use the Event ID:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{event-id}/attending?access_token=xxx
```

You can´t get all attendees for all events in one API call, you have to do this event by event. Test it in the [API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) before using any PHP code.

Btw, you should use `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents`. The PHP SDK uses `CURL` too.

Comment: Thanks for reply...But i am not getting the issue. Whatever i send in request like if i send simple request which should return basic info like https://graph.facebook.com/my_fb_name then also its returning false in curl response and if i paste this url into urlbar it returns correct results.

Comment: read some tutorials about curl, you can activate the debugging mode, you can show headers and whatnot. it´s very important to know how to debug stuff in php. but the curl part was only a side note anyway.